# Configure postfix to run filter only with selected mail else all other mail pass without being filtered

Tags: php, email, postfix, ubuntu-10.04

I am running postfix and I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

I created php script and i injected it into postfix to filter incoming mail. All run as I wish.

But Now I want my postfix to run filter only with selected mail (for example I will run filter when mail contains pdf attachments) else all other mail ( that don't contain pdf attach) pass without being filtered (without running filter.)

I have been searching the net however not getting proper help to understand thoroughly. I found configuration below:

```
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/blocked_attachments
```

But I understand that this config block mail. ( I don't want to block any mail, I want mails either to be passed by filter or pass normally without being filtered)

Is it possible to achieve my aim or should I have to code this with php into my script.

Earliest response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what the `mime_header_checks` directive does it to instruct postfix to check an external table (/etc/postfix/blocked_attachments, in your case) for a matching pattern and action.

But to correctly use it you should *really* read the [relevant postfix man page](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html)

Comment: What I understand that mime_header_checks either pass mail into filter or rejected it !!! more explanation please.

Comment: mime_header_checks  simply instruct postfix to match each incoming email against the regular expression listed inside the /etc/postfix/blocked_attachments file. When a regexp match, it will execute the corresponding action. I linked the documentation in the answer. Please read it.